# Can I use scanf to capture a directive with a width specified by a variable?

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code:

```
scanf(" %Xs %Ys", buf1, buf2);
```

Where X and Y should be integers. The problem is that the values for X and Y are compile-time constants, and even if I wanted to hard-code the values into the format string, I can't, because I don't know the values. In printf, you can send a width variable along with the arguments with "%*s". Is there anything analogous for scanf?

EDIT: To clarify, constants are known at *compile* time, but not at *coding* time, and not by me at all.  They may vary by platform or implementation, and they may change after I'm done. Even did they not, I still wouldn't want to have buffer sizes duplicated in format strings, ready to segfault the minute I forget to keep them synchronized.

Comment: Compile-time constants are known at compile time, aren't they, so the values could be built into the string?  But then you say you don't know the values so you can't code them...The question seems self-contradictory.

Comment: As you are probably aware, the '*' in `scanf()` means "suppress any assignment for this value".  There isn't anything analogous to '*' in `printf()` for `scanf()`.  Kernighan & Pike do as @sambowry suggests in 'The Practice of Programming'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may produce the format string with sprintf():

```
sprintf( format, " %%%is %%%is", X, Y );
scanf(format, buf1, buf2);
```

EDIT: amazing, but the following gcc code is working:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define LIST(...) __VA_ARGS__ 

#define scanf_param( fmt, param, str, args ) {  \ 
  char fmt2[100]; \ 
  sprintf( fmt2, fmt, LIST param ); \ 
  sscanf( str, fmt2, LIST args  ); \ 
} 

enum { X=3 };
#define Y X+1 

int main(){
  char str1[10], str2[10];

  scanf_param( " %%%is %%%is", (X,Y), " 123 4567", (&str1, &str2) );

  printf("str1: '%s'   str2: '%s'\n", str1, str2 );
}
```

Comment: Waste of runtime resources if the numbers are constants, don't you think?

Comment: It is true, but more flexible. It is working when X and Y read from a file, etc.

Comment: @LIraNuna: No - not a waste of runtime resources (because one part of the question says "values not known at compile-time" - though another part says "values are compile-time constants").  This is the way Kernighan & Pike deal with the problem in 'The Practice of Programming' because there isn't an easy alternative that is reliable.

Comment: I think you need to change `LIST param` to `LIST(param)` - any compiler accepting the first form is wrong and needs fixing.

Comment: @Chris: the 'param' contains the necessary parenthesis. [ 'LIST param' --> 'LIST (X,Y)' --> 'X,Y' ]

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that the values for X
>   and Y are compile-time constants

Then use macro paste feature:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST 2

#define CONST_TO_STRING_(x) #x
#define CONST_TO_STRING(x) CONST_TO_STRING_(x)

int main() {
    printf("1 " CONST_TO_STRING(TEST) " 3\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the compile-time constants are defined as something other than a simple unadorned integer, for example `sizeof foo`, `10 * 2`, `500UL`, `0x20` and `'\n'` will all fail.

Comment: OP didn't say how those constants are declared. If this is not his/her case, the question should be edited.

Comment: The OP said they were "compile-time constants", a term which encompasses all of the constants in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you don't know the values, then they are probably *run-time* constants, not compile-time constants.

If that's the case (i.e. they are run-time consants), then no, there's no such feature in 'scanf'. The only thing you can do is to produce the complete format string (with the concrete values embedded in it) at run-time by using 'sprintf' and then pass that format string to your 'scanf'.

Comment: There can easily be unknown compile-time constants - ever heard of `#ifdef` ?

Comment: Well, when I say "unknown", I mean "unknown to the compiler at the time of compilation", becaus in my opinion this is the only relevant form of "unknown". '#define'd manifest constants known at the time of compilation can be embedded into the format string by the preprocessor (already answered here).