# Using a DEFINITION in a scanf in C (type specifier)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, scanf, c-preprocessor

So my original code was:

```
scanf("%20s %20s", Player1.name, Player2.name);
```

If I want to make my code more flexible can I do, or is there a similar way to do:

```
.#define MAX_NAME_IN 20
...
scanf("%MAX_NAME_INs %MAX_NAME_INs", Player1.name, Player2.name);
...
```

Comment: Can you give us example what you would like to read... then answers would be better

Comment: Have you seen this: [Can I use scanf to capture a directive with a width specified by a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549906/758831)?

Comment: nope, `%MAX_NAME_INs` will not  be replaced by `%20s`

Comment: For a Microsoft-only solution, you can used `scanf_s`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/18836661/318716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define MAX_NAME_IN 20
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)
...
scanf("%" S(MAX_NAME_IN) "s %" S(MAX_NAME_IN) "s", Player1.name, Player2.name);
```

---

replace by preprocessor like this

```
S(MAX_NAME_IN) => S_(20) => "20"

scanf("%" S(MAX_NAME_IN) "s %" S(MAX_NAME_IN) "s", Player1.name, Player2.name);
↓
scanf("%" "20" "s %" "20" "s", Player1.name, Player2.name);
```

and `"%" "20" "s %" "20" "s"` is interpreted as `"%20s %20s"` by compiler.

Comment: oh awesome, can you please explain how this works?

Comment: why could you not have done #define MAX_NAME_IN 20                      #define S(x) #x?

Comment: @Theo your case is converted as follows: `S(MAX_NAME_IN)` => `"MAX_NAME_IN"`