# Trying to pass maximum number of characters read by scanf through #define

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a number to `scanf` of how many characters I want to  read from the input stream. However, I can't get it to work.

My code works when I just put the number in the code, but I want to pass the number through `#define` to change it easily.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char tab[11];

    printf("Podaj tekst: ");
    scanf("%10[^\n]", tab);

    printf("%s", tab);
}
```

This doesn't work (it only gets characters up until first whitespace character):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 10

int main(void)
{
    char tab[size+1];

    printf("Podaj tekst: ");
    scanf("%size[^\n]", tab);

    printf("%s", tab);
}
```

It seems strange to me that it doesn't work. Is there any workaround to do what I want (besides using `fgets`)?

Comment: `"%size[^\n]"` is the same as `"%s" "ize[^\n]"`.

Comment: @chux That makes sense, any idea how I can escape that 'size' into the scanf?

Comment: See [Can I use scanf to capture a directive with a width specified by a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549906/2410359)

Comment: kunek, An even better approach is to use `fgets()` and ditch `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux Looks like `fgets()` is a better approach here, thanks!

Comment: See also [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert numerals or other text to strings with the preprocessor `#` operator. This requires using two macros, one to expand the `size` macro and another to apply the operator:

```
#define size 10

#define StringifyHelper(x)  #x
#define Stringify(x)        StringifyHelper(x)

...

char tab[size+1];
scanf("%" Stringify(size) "[^\n]", tab);
```